# Strategy for converting JSON to DBM Hash File (AEM with Apache backend)

Tags: json, apache, aem, dbm

I'm looking for some solution design assistance, as an idea I thought I could mimic apache's [httxt2dbm](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/httxt2dbm.html) tool.

Use case: 
We currently manage our 301 RewriteRule's in apache for our AEM environment. My co-worker has built a webform for end users to submit their redirect requests and this puts the form data in MongoDB.

Problem:
How can I convert JSON into a dbm hash file like the httxt2bdm tool does?

Any ideas for how to tackle this problem?

The end goal here is that users can fill in the webform, then a cronjob will run and update apache followed by restarting httpd.

I know about the [map manager](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/redirect-map-manager/index.html) tool but it doesn't really fit the use case.